# Splitting one Pandas column on values from a different column in the same row?

Tags: regex, pandas

I have some DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'pear'], 'columnB': ['XAXappleYBY', 'ZZZbananaRDESWA', 'HDJFpeachIUYTA', 'POIUYpearMNBV']})

    columnA columnB
0   apple   XAXappleYBY
1   banana  ZZZbananaRDESWA
2   peach   HDJFpeachIUYTA
3   pear    POIUYpearMNBV
```

I would like to split `columnB` on the string in `columnA` and expand, e.g.:

```
    columnA columnB left_split  right_split
0   apple   XaXappleYBY XaX YBY
1   banana  ZZZbananaRDESWa ZZZ RDESWa
2   peach   HDJFpeachIUYTA  HDJF    IUYTA
3   pear    POIUYpearMNBV   POIUY   MNBV
```

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string `split` with listcomp and construct dataframe `df1`. Finally, join back to `df`

```
cols = ['columnA', 'columnB']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(pat) for pat, x in  zip(*map(df.get, cols))], 
                    columns=['left_split', 'right_split'])
df_final = df.join(df1)

Out[153]:
  columnA          columnB left_split right_split
0   apple      XAXappleYBY        XAX         YBY
1  banana  ZZZbananaRDESWA        ZZZ      RDESWA
2   peach   HDJFpeachIUYTA       HDJF       IUYTA
3    pear    POIUYpearMNBV      POIUY        MNBV
```

---

Explanation on `[x.split(pat) for pat, x in  zip(*map(df.get, cols))]`:

`zip(*map(df.get, cols))` is just another way of writing for `zip(df.columnA, df.columnB)` in this case. It is convenient on dataframe with many columns. It is just my habit to use the `zip-map` version :)

```
[x.split(pat) for pat, x in  zip(*map(df.get, cols))]

Out[198]: [['XAX', 'YBY'], ['ZZZ', 'RDESWA'], ['HDJF', 'IUYTA'], ['POIUY', 'MNB']]

[x.split(pat) for pat, x in  zip(df.columnA, df.columnB)]

Out[199]: [['XAX', 'YBY'], ['ZZZ', 'RDESWA'], ['HDJF', 'IUYTA'], ['POIUY', 'MNBV']]
```

It zips 2 columns. On each iteration of list comprehension it slices corresponding value of each column. I.e., on each iteration, it slices a tuple corresponding to each row of `columnA` and `columnB`. Each tuple is unpacked to `pat`, `x` where `pat` is value of `columnA` and `x` is value of `columnB`. x is the string you want to split, so call `x.split(pat)` will split each string of `columnB` by each `pat` of `columnA`

Comment: Do I need to specify `columnA` or `columnB`? Missing from the example (sorry) are a bunch of unrelated columns in the DataFrame, some of which contain strings.

Comment: oh, if your dataframe has more columns, you need to specify column you want to split. I guess I should use specifiec columns in my code. I edited the answer to use specific columns

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you mind adding some additional notes on this line: `[x.split(pat) for pat, x in  zip(*map(df.get, cols))]`?

Comment: I added more explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, maybe it'd be OK to look at this simple expression:

```
^([A-Z]*)([a-z]*)([A-Z]*)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2J8mQ/1/)

#### Test

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'pear'], 'columnB': [
                  'XAXappleYBY', 'ZZZbananaRDESWA', 'HDJFpeachIUYTA', 'POIUYpearMNBV']})


df['left_split'] = df['columnB'].str.replace(r'^([A-Z]*)([a-z]*)([A-Z]*)', r'\1')
df['right_split'] = df['columnB'].str.replace(r'^([A-Z]*)([a-z]*)([A-Z]*)', r'\3')
print(df)
```

#### Output

```
  columnA          columnB left_split right_split
0   apple      XAXappleYBY        XAX         YBY
1  banana  ZZZbananaRDESWA        ZZZ      RDESWA
2   peach   HDJFpeachIUYTA       HDJF       IUYTA
3    pear    POIUYpearMNBV      POIUY        MNBV
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/g2J8mQ/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/g2J8mQ/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
regpattern = '|'.join(df['columnA'])

df[['left_split','right_split']]=df['columnB'].str.split(regpattern, expand=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  columnA          columnB left_split right_split
0   apple      XAXappleYBY        XAX         YBY
1  banana  ZZZbananaRDESWA        ZZZ      RDESWA
2   peach   HDJFpeachIUYTA       HDJF       IUYTA
3    pear    POIUYpearMNBV      POIUY        MNBV
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer so far. Seems like the most obvious solution.

Comment: @TipsyHyena: it's a very clean solution. However, it has its limit. Make sure that each string doesn't have 2 different patterns from different rows in it such as:  if row 0: columnA = `apple`, columnB=`XAXappleYBYpeachNAYN`, it will split to `XAX`, `YBY`, `NAYN`. Otherwise, it is a nice solution :)

Comment: I'm glad you pointed that out, because my DataFrame in question does contain exactly what you mentioned.

Comment: @TipsyHyena In the case that AndyL. has described.  What would like like returned?  Thanks AndyL for point this limitation out.   I will see if I can fix with this current code once I verify the expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+\s+(?<fruit>\w+)\s+\w+(?<middle>\k<fruit>)\w+
```

[Here is the answer you need](https://regex101.com/r/ENDRva/2/)

The input is your table without the first line(the title), find the named group "middle" and replace them with empty characters as you like.

**The explanation:**

`\d+\s+` locate the leading numbers and spaces
`(?<fruit>\w+)` find the fruits you'd like to use them for splitting, and name the group as "fruit".
`w+(?<middle>\k<fruit>)\w+` use previous named "fruit" as searching condition to match, and name the matched group "middle"